# Swift: Issue with closure arguments

Tags: swift, arguments, closures

Here is a function:

`func foo(completion: (jsonData: String) -> ()) {
}`

In Swift 3, you can't have argument labels. Therefore, this is the code:

`func foo(completion: (String) -> ()) {
}`

The issue with this, is that when I call the function it looks like this:

`foo(completion: { _ in
})`

So, if I want to see the value of `jsonData`, I can't because it's an underscore. How would I solve this issue?

Comment: by not placing an underscore there but an actual variable name you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working:

```
func foo(completion: (String) -> ()) {
    completion("Hi")
}

foo { jsonData in
    print(jsonData) // Output: Hi
}
```